# C# Ограничить создание экземпляра класса

Tags: c#

Всем привет.

Краткое описание проблемы: Есть классы Info, Foo, Too. Класс Info является "главным" среди классов Foo и Too и имеет внутри себя свойства с гетерами и сетерами (пример кода ниже)

```
public class Info
{
    public Foo Foo {get;set;}
    public Too Too {get;set;}

    public Info()
    {
        Foo = new Foo();
        Too = new Too();
    }
}
```

Так же, классы Foo и Too имеют внутри себя некую логику, доступ к которой можно получить через экземпляр данного класса (свойство, которое устанавливается в классе Info). Алгоритм получения значений из этих классов:

```
new Info().Foo.AnyVariableAndMethod
```

Но при этом всём, доступ к экземпляру Foo или Too можно получить и извне класса Info. Например, написав что-то подобное:

```
new Foo().AnyVariableAndMethod
```

Вопрос: Как ограничить доступ к созданию экземпляров классов Foo и Too, позволив "общаться" с ними только через экземпляр класса Info?

P.S. Вариант, с перемещением логики классов Foo и Too в класс Info, точно не подходит, т.к. объём кода очень сильно увеличится, а его читаемость уменьшится. Есть-ли какой-нибудь ещё вариант без создания приватных конструкторов и тд?

Comment: Для того, чтоб класс нельзя было создать через `new()`, его делают абстрактным (`abstract class Foo {}`), в этом случае, он может быть использован только при наследовании в другом классе.

Comment: в чем принципиальная разница между `new Info().Foo.AnyVariableAndMethod` и `new Foo().AnyVariableAndMethod`? Можешь попробовать сделать классы internal, тогда они будут публичными только внутри одной сборки

Comment: Точно! Абстрактные классы. Давненько их не использовал и совсем вылетело из головы. Спасибо. Решено